# Importing LEGO scenes add-on error

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, import

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhbxq07CB2U) to create my custom LEGO scenes & characters and render them out in blender but I am getting some errors.

Basically, I have downloaded this software ([Studio by Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/download.page)) to make custom LEGO scenes. Now this software exports the 3D files in the format .ldr so I am using this add-on [ImportLDraw](https://github.com/TobyLobster/ImportLDraw). I have installed it blender. Now this add-on requires a library of LEGO pieces so I am using the one in the folder of Studio. Now when I try to import it in blender, I am getting this error.

[image]

How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`def loadFromFile(context, filename, isFullFilepath=True)`](https://github.com/TobyLobster/ImportLDraw/blob/722a6d784f7f2c41a9cffc89ae4ff012fc465e08/loadldraw/loadldraw.py#L4209) assumes that there is a camera in your scene. [It tries to retrieve it](https://github.com/TobyLobster/ImportLDraw/blob/722a6d784f7f2c41a9cffc89ae4ff012fc465e08/loadldraw/loadldraw.py#L4283), but doesn't check if the returned value is `None`:

```
scene  = bpy.context.scene
camera = scene.camera
```

Later it assigns a location to the camera, which fails when there is no camera in the scene. This causes the exception in [line 4337](https://github.com/TobyLobster/ImportLDraw/blob/722a6d784f7f2c41a9cffc89ae4ff012fc465e08/loadldraw/loadldraw.py#L4337) that you're seeing.

```
camera.location = mathutils.Vector((6.5, -6.5, 4.75))
```

You can solve the problem by adding a camera to your scene and setting it as active camera. [This issue has been fixed in the 2.80 version of the add-on.](https://github.com/TobyLobster/ImportLDraw/blob/e937739e2d454fd309c413378e687b5a2489040e/loadldraw/loadldraw.py#L4353)

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.